# not able to extend class using package

Tags: java, package

i have one package named MyPackage1 that contains 2 public classes one is called Output.java and another one is Input.java
code for Output.java file is given below

```
package MyPackage1;
 public abstract class Output
    {
        public static void outln(String str)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        public void outlnn(String str)
        {
            System.out.println(str+"\n");
        }
        public void noutln(String str)
        {
            System.out.println("\n"+str);
        }
        public void out(String str)
        {
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        public void nout(String str)
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+str);
        }
    }
```

another class class called Input.java have code that is given below.

```
package MyPackage1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Input extends Output   //error
{
    static BufferedReader  br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static DataInputStream dr=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    static Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);

        public static String bcin() throws IOException
        {

            System.out.print("Input the Value : ");
            String string111=br.readLine();
            return(string111);
        }
        public static String dcin() throws IOException
        {
            System.out.print("Input the Value : ");
            String string111=dr.readLine();
            return(string111);
        }
```

whenever i try to compile Input i am geeting some error.link for screenshot is [image]

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message you get. Tell us how you compile.

Comment: **Don't** use deprecated method [DataInputStream#readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29).

Comment: Make sure that `.class` file is generated and placed at targeted path.

Comment: did you try to clean and Build your project? which IDE do you use?

Comment: @Braj .class file of both java file are in same folder.The name of that folder is MyPackage1

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compile Input.java. Input extends the Output class. And Output.java is not compiled yet, and is not in the source path of the compiler. The easiest way is thus to compile both classes at once. Go to the directory containing MyPackage1, and type

```
javac MyPackage1\Input.java MyPackage1\Output.java
```

A few notes though:

- Java 5 is completely out of date. We're now at Java 8. Download it and use this version.
- Don't store your source files into the JDK's bin directory. That's where the JDK's binaries are. Your source files should be elsewhere.
- Use the -d option of javac to store your .class files in a directory that is different from your source directory.
- Respect the Java naming conventions. Packages are all lowercase.
- I really don't see why Output should be an abstract class, and why Input should extend Output. Is an input an output? If not, it shouldn't extend it.

Comment: :-I also compile this program in jdk1.8 and jdk1.7, everywhere same problem.I extends output class in Input class because I want to use simple function name instead of System.out.println().